# Creating a cronjob from a makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile, cron

I am trying to let my makefile setup a cronjob for my application. Unfortunately it appears to not be working as the `$CRONENTRY` variable seems to be empty. What am I doing wrong here?

```
addcron:
    CRONENTRY="*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/node cronapp.js >> logfile.log"
    crontab -l | { cat; echo ${CRONENTRY}; } | crontab -
```

Comment: This sounds like a valid question (I reached here looking for same info), why down vote? I hate when people down vote without a comment on "why". SO should make that as a rule!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each command in a rule executes in its own subshell; variables do not survive from one command to the next. So if you want to use a variable this way, you have to string the commands together.

```
addcron:
    CRONENTRY="whatever" ; \
  do_something_with $(CRONENTRY)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
addcron:
    CRONENTRY=
    { crontab -l; echo "*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/node cronapp.js >> logfile.log" } | crontab -
```

- there you have one less pipe element...